# AVD - Changes not applied?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I made changes to an app, just changing the icons. That worked, I was able to see the results when I launched the emulator.

I tried to create a new app but when I launched the emulator again I saw my previous app. I have tried to wipe the user data but it doesn't change anything.

Edit: I saw my previous app but the new app didn't appear.

I eventually deleted the projects, the source code and then restarting eclipse but I'm still having the problems. When I launch the virtual device again it's still showing the original app. I've also tried creating a new emulator as well but I have the same .

Anyone else having this problem or know what's going on?

P.S I also tried loading the Halo theme but it doesn't load.

(Using Mac OS X Lion & Eclipse Classic 3.7 (32 bit))

Comment: Does the eclipse console mention anything (`Window -> Show View -> Console`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the name of your applicaition package to cause this behaviour?

Just uninstall the old app from the emulator.

```
Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> YourApp -> Uninstall
```